# Error after data-migration-tool update

Tags: magento2.4, migration, data-migration-tool, monolog

After updating data-migration-tool I get this error every time I try to run the command:

```
  Warning: Could not check compatibility between Migration\Logger\Logger::addRecord(int $level, string $message, array $context = Array, ?Migration\Logger\DateTimeImmutable $datetime = NULL): bool and Monolog\Logger::addRecord(int $level, string $message, array $context = Array,   
  ?Monolog\DateTimeImmutable $datetime = NULL): bool, because class Migration\Logger\DateTimeImmutable is not available in public_html/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Logger/Logger.php on line 34
```

How can I come back to the earlier version of data-migration-tool? Is it possible or should I made changes in Logger file?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution: Magento requires version ^2.6 of monolog, which means that 2.7.0 is the highest version that is installed when your composer create-project of Magento.

So, you need to execute the command:

```
composer require monolog/monolog:2.6 
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

As a reference: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/35604#issuecomment-1158838365